# SCID vs ChessBase - play, analyse, visualization - ubuntu

Tags: analysis, chessbase, scid, linux, visualization

Please help me or give me the correct terms to find it out.

What I want is:

- Play chess against an engine or repeat an existing game
- For my current move, I want an analyser to analyse my move, and a visualiation (not only text) to show me (better) alternatives.

What I tried:

- I installed SCID, with Stockfish, and loaded some PNG games or, doing: 'serious game' and play against stockfish
- I can see some analysis text running at a window. However, that is sort of exhausting. 
  What I want: having an arrow that shows me what to move where; after I have done my move.
  Either by: analysing my move, and showing a better alternative. Or, showing me what the player (whose game I just play) was doing

My questions: how is it called, what I want? Does this exist, especially a visualization?

It is not necessary to use SCID, however, I failed to install SCID vs PC and Lukas Chess.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you simply use a browser, and play online at chess.com, lichess.com, or chess24.com. While chess.com and chess24.com have paid versions too, all three have the ability to create an account, and play online, including against computers.

You also have the option to use online engines to analyze your games.

Answer (score 1):

try Lucas chess. It's free and works in windows and Linux using wine. It has a tutor option that is really visual and also many engines you can select based on your rating level
https://lucaschess.pythonanywhere.com/